# Google Storage - Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, axios, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to download files from google storage in my front-end (Vue.js). I've made and API in my backend (node.js) to [List Files](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/master/samples/listFiles.js) so I get back an array of objects. The API request is made using Axios:

```
axios.get(url)
    .then(response => {
        this.files = response.data
    })
```

So I store the bucket files in the "files" array and loop through it. The download link is the [mediaLink](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_storage_.objectmetadata.html#medialink) that is part of the object I get from the API.

```
<div class="files center" v-for="file in files" :key="file.id">   
    <a v-bind:href="file.metadata.mediaLink">{{ file.name }}</a>
</div>
```

The thing is that when I click on the mediaLink I get this message:

```
Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to BUCKET_NAME/BUCKET_FILE.pdf.
```

My front-end have Firebase Auth with Google account and I'm logged in with the admin account of the Google Cloud project where the files are. Why it says I'm an anonymous caller when I'm already logged in?

Here is how I'm logging in as requested:

```
login(){
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()

    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then((result) => {
        this.token = result.credential.accessToken;
        this.user = result.user;
        this.$router.push({ name: 'Files' });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log('SignInWithPopup Error: ' + err.message)
    })
}
```

In the Firebase Console it appears the login credentials:
[Firebase console capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2B1Qi.png)

Comment: *I'm logged in with the admin account of the Google Cloud project where the files are* - you're possibly not, because you get this error. The code you posted doesn't confirm that. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem.

Comment: @EstusFlask I editted the post with more info